# HTML5 video CC button disappears when clicked on

Tags: html, video, html5-video

When putting the SRC links for HTML5 video on a page, the TRACK only seems to work if the it exists localy to that HTML file. We like to keep all our videos and caption files on a separate server, so this is a huge issue.

If the track looks like this, they display fine:

```
<track src="captions.vtt">
```

If the VTT file is on another server and the track looks like this, the CC button disappears when you click on it and the captions never show up:

```
<track src="http://anotherserver.com/captions.vtt">
```

This happens in Chrome and Opera. No captions are displayed at all in Edge or IE, but at least the button doesn't disappear.

Comment: A little more info after some additional testing...
When I moved the HTML files to that remote server I noticed that:
- local calls worked.
- http calls worked (page is called via http).
- https calls fail.
When I use HTTPS for the page (this server has a certificate) I noticed that:
- local calls worked.
- http calls fail.
- https calls worked (page is called via https).

Comment: So, it would seem that there is some sort of browser security issue that I'm not sure how to work with yet. I know with the Flash Player version, I had to put a crossdomain.xml file to allow the XML captions to work. Haven't found what works for HTML5 VIDEO calls on a VTT file though.

Answer (score 1):

Changed my video tag from this:

```
<video poster="...." controls>
```

to this by adding **crossorigin="anonymous"** to it:

```
<video poster="...." crossorigin="anonymous" controls>
```

And added a web.config file to the server that holds all our VTT files that contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That is CORS and it's an XML file (i.e. cors.xml). If OP runs files from S3 then it's easy.

Comment: Yes, I did finally realize it was CORS, though I'm not a server guru and for me it's not easy at all, and all of the solutions I found were either just server side or client side. The solution that worked for me was a combination. Not sure what you mean by "if OP runs files from S3."

Comment: OP is Original Post or Original Poster can be interpreted as the posted question or the question's poster. Amazon Web Services S3 Simple Storage.

Comment: Thank for clarifying that. We don't use S3, it's our own IIS 8 server.